# need equal number of ones in all columns placed at random position in np array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have made a function to get equal number of ones placed at random position in all rows.
Below is the function:

```
def func():
final = np.zeros((c))

for i in range(r):
  data = list(range(0, c))
  
  random.shuffle(data)
  data = data[:n_of_ones_in_row]
  
  array = np.zeros(c)
  for i in data:
    array[i] = 1 

  final = np.vstack((final,array))
  final_del = np.delete(final , 0,0)
return final_del
```

but now if I am trying to balance equal number of ones in columns my number of ones in rows got unbalanced. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Expected output:
https://i.postimg.cc/zfQZ1PnF/b0b70fe3fb442a4c0e5bfe7d366ad467.png

Comment: This is the expected output all the yes are ones 
 all the rows have equal number of ones and all columns have equal number of ones https://i.postimg.cc/zfQZ1PnF/b0b70fe3fb442a4c0e5bfe7d366ad467.png

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import random as rng

###### Input
n = number_of_ones = 2
a = square_array_dimension = 7

###### Setting up initial matrix
r = Random_ones_array = np.zeros((a,a),dtype=int)
for k in range(a):
    for j in range(n):    
        m = j+k
        r[m%a][k] = 1
print(r) 

###### Shuffle indices
idx1=list(range(a))
rng.shuffle(idx1) # these functions directly modify their input...
idx2=list(range(a))
rng.shuffle(idx2)

###### Apply shuffling to matrix
r=r[idx1,:]
r=r[:,idx2]

###### Output: A shuffled matrix
print(r)
```

The idea is to start with an initial array that fits your criteria, then shuffle rows and columns independently in succession.

Edit: Just realized, that not all possible solutions can be obtained this way. Specifically degenerate columns or rows are not allowed, based on the initial matrix, if this is desired to be included the solution will be more complicated then what I wrote here...